# Insert selected values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have table **users** with vallues :

```
FirstName     LastName     Age
 A               A          20
 B               B          21
 C               C          22
 D               D          21
 E               E          20
```

Have procedure where I select values from this table , then want sorting and insert to another tables, I do it like :

```
SELECT @firstName = FirstName ,lastName = LastName ,@age = Age FROM dbo.users
if @age = 20
insert into tbl1(FirstName,LastName) values (@firstName,@LastName )
if @age = 21
insert into tbl2(FirstName,LastName) values (@firstName,@LastName )
if @age = 22
insert into tbl3(FirstName,LastName) values (@firstName,@LastName )
```

When I do like this ,all rows dont insert to tables, i think need loop or something for do it, can anyone help me ? I want do it without cursor

Comment: @MahmoudGamal because then I want change insert to procedure nad there will be some procedures

Comment: i am not able to understand what you want ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap these codes inside your procedure.

```
insert into tbl1(FirstName,LastName) SELECT FirstName ,LastName FROM dbo.users WHERE Age = 20;
insert into tbl2(FirstName,LastName) SELECT FirstName ,LastName FROM dbo.users WHERE Age = 21;
insert into tbl3(FirstName,LastName) SELECT FirstName ,LastName FROM dbo.users WHERE Age = 22;
```

Comment: No. He is inserting into different tables

Answer (score 0):

```
    begin tran

    declare @firstName varchar(20)
    declare @lastName varchar(20)
    declare @age int

    SELECT @firstName = firstName,
                 @lastName = lastName,
                 @age = Age 

    FROM dbo.users

    if @age = 20
    begin
    insert into tbl1
    select @firstName,@LastName from dbo.users where @age = 20
    end

    if @age = 21
    begin
    insert into tbl2
    select @firstName,@LastName from dbo.users where @age = 21
    end

    if @age = 22
    begin
    insert into tbl3
    select @firstName,@LastName from dbo.users where @age = 22
    end

    --check
    select * from tbl1
    select * from tbl2
    select * from tbl3

rollback tran

--commit tran
```